# Overriding second level graph extension method in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I need to work with the reusable business objects for Sales tax, discounts, etc. and need to override some of the methods in these graph extensions. For example I am starting with the Opportunities graph. I have a set of order totals that need to calculate into the overall products amount and in the past we just overrode the tax attribute on (I think) tax category. Anyhow I don't see how its possible to use the `PXOverrideAttribute` on a method from a second level graph extension.

Here is my example:

```
public class OpportunityMaintExtOne : PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.CR.OpportunityMaint.SalesTax, PX.Objects.CR.OpportunityMaint>
{ 
    [PXOverride]
    public virtual void CalcDocTotals(object row, decimal CuryTaxTotal, decimal CuryInclTaxTotal, decimal CuryWhTaxTotal,
        Action<object, decimal, decimal, decimal> del)
    {
        del?.Invoke(row, CuryTaxTotal, CuryInclTaxTotal, CuryWhTaxTotal);

        var someOtherTotal = Base1.Documents.Cache.GetValueAsDecimal<CROpportunityExtension.aMCurySomeOtherTotal>(row);
        if (someOtherTotal == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        var curyDocTotal = someOtherTotal + Base1.Documents.Cache.GetValueAsDecimal<CROpportunity.curyProductsAmount>(row);
        Base1.Documents.Cache.SetValue<CROpportunity.curyProductsAmount>(row, curyDocTotal);
    }
}
```

What is going on inside of *CalcDocTotals* in my graph extension is not the focus. It is the fact that I cannot override the `OpportunityMaint.SalesTax CalcDocTotals` method as I could if the method was in the first level (Base) graph. The SalesTax graph extension has the method as protected but protected methods (if it was in the base graph) are overrideable using the PXOverrideAttribute if you make your method call public which is what I have done. I also tried using a declared delegate in place of the Action but same results (as I expected but wanted to confirm).

My question: **Is it possible to override a second, third, etc. level graph extension method using the PXOverrideAttribute?**

When I compile the code above and the page loads I get this error:

> Method Void CalcDocTotals(System.Object, System.Decimal,
>   System.Decimal, System.Decimal,
>   System.Action`4[System.Object,System.Decimal,System.Decimal,System.Decimal])
>   in graph extension is marked as [PXOverride], but the original method
>   with such name has not been found in PXGraph

Comment: I think currently the system is trying to find the `CalcDocTotals` in the `OpportunityMaint` graph.But that is only one of the several problems. The second problem is that `CalcDocTotals` is member of the abstract class and in the `SalesTax` graph it is protected and just overrode.

Comment: As an idea I can suggest to try to implement the `TaxGraph` abstract class and at some point replace the `SalesTax` with it

Comment: The problem is that Acumatica is already declaring the use of SalesTax. If we declare it again I would assume we would get a double execution/results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ability to override extension methods from a higher level extension has been added in 2018R1 Update 4 (18.104.0023). This resolves my question/issue and allows for the code posted in my question to function as is.

Comment: I am using 19R2 and I'm not seeing this ability. I'm getting the error you get above with my extension function, and I do not see it as an overridable function in the Override Method action in the Code section of the Customization Project Editor. Any hints as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @EricP. I would post this as a new question if not already. It would be better to see your setup. Just include your class declaration for the graph extension and the one method you are trying to extend should be enough

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override methods from Extension1 in Extension2 etc as far as I've been able to see in my years with Acumatica. My solution to the problem was thus : Create a helper graph with your basic methodology, create a field or property for it in whatever graph you wish to use it in (Preferably a Lazy initialized one), then in whatever project you must override the logic on, just reference your original project, and create an extension of your helper graph.

Comment: Thanks. From what I am hearing from your post an others is its not possible. Because I am not in control of "Extension1" I do not see how the graph helper would assist here. I am working with Acumatica graph extensions which need to be extendable which appear to not be possible. It seems like a limitation when using reusable business objects: https://help.acumatica.com/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=76b8c160-89bd-4501-9f9f-1dabc648d417  we have implemented reusable business logic for our graph extensions and it works well before someone else needs to extend any virtual methods.