# How do I edit a BLC extension that is part of out-of-the-box Acumatica, specifically SM_CRCaseMaint.cs?

Tags: acumatica

I need to add some logic to the CreateServiceOrder action that is shown on the CRCaseMaint screen. I've discovered that the logic actually exists in the file called SM_CRCaseMaint.cs in a class that is an extension of CRCaseMaint. This file is part of base Acumatica, so it is already an extension but cannot be edited directly without risk of losing the changes when the instance is updated. When I attempt to create a graph extension:

[image]

I get an error:

[image]

Is there any way I can edit this page?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Brendan's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51049526/7376238), as of Acumatica version 2018R1 Update 4 (18.104.0023) you can override or redefine the content of the graph extension shipped with the product.

I did a test with CreateServiceOrder action in version 2018R2 and it worked. The debugger did break into the redefined action when I invoked Create Service Order action from a case:

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.FS;

namespace PX.Objects.CR
{
    public class CRCaseMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<CRCaseMaint>
    {
        [PXCopyPasteHiddenView]
        public PXFilter<FSCreateServiceOrderOnCaseFilter> CreateServiceOrderFilter;

        public PXAction<CRCase> CreateServiceOrder;
        [PXButton]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Create Service Order", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
        public virtual void createServiceOrder()
        {
            CRCase crCaseRow = Base.Case.Current;
            FSxCRCase fsxCRCaseRow = Base.Case.Cache.GetExtension<FSxCRCase>(crCaseRow);

            if (CreateServiceOrderFilter.AskExt() == WebDialogResult.OK)
            {
                Base.Case.SetValueExt<FSxCRCase.sDEnabled>(crCaseRow, true);
                Base.Case.SetValueExt<FSxCRCase.branchLocationID>(crCaseRow, CreateServiceOrderFilter.Current.BranchLocationID);
                Base.Case.SetValueExt<FSxCRCase.srvOrdType>(crCaseRow, CreateServiceOrderFilter.Current.SrvOrdType);
                Base.Case.SetValueExt<FSxCRCase.assignedEmpID>(crCaseRow, CreateServiceOrderFilter.Current.AssignedEmpID);
                Base.Case.SetValueExt<FSxCRCase.problemID>(crCaseRow, CreateServiceOrderFilter.Current.ProblemID);
                Base.Case.Cache.SetStatus(crCaseRow, PXEntryStatus.Updated);
                Base.Save.Press();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for so long for me to get back to you but I was pulled onto other projects. I tried exactly what you have here, but it is not stepping into my code. It isn't even changing the name of the button if I change it to something else. I copied and pasted the function you created, so it looks exactly the same as above. I have other functions which are being hit, and I don't think they would influence the button either. Any suggestions to look into?

Comment: The feature is version sensitive. Did you try it on the versions suggested in the answer?

Comment: Yes, the current version I'm using is 18R2, 18.206.0011. There is also Manufacturing and Construction being used in this system. I'm not sure if those will change anything, but it's worth a mention.

Comment: The pattern to override should be to simply copy paste the action member variable and action event handler along with the attributes in the extension. You can check that prototypes match by using Acumatica source code page. Besides that when you publish you need to set Level of the customization in the project editor accordingly so that the highest level is the one with the redefined method.